# angularjs - get ng-repeat element using element.html() inside a jsPanel directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to create a directive which will take the html content and place it n a [jsPanel element](https://github.com/Flyer53/jsPanel).

So far I am able to compile the scope and able get elements with the scope. Then i tried to get html tag with `ng-repeat`, where i got stuck.
Following is the code used to create the **directive**

```
mainApp.directive('jspanelcontent', function($compile) {
    console.log("loading");
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'AE';
    directive.compile = function(element, attributes) {
        var linkFunction = function($scope, element, attributes) {
            console.log(element.html());
            var contenthtml = element.html();
            contenthtml = angular.element($compile(contenthtml)($scope));
            element.html("");
            $scope.jspanleinstance = $.jsPanel({
                position: {
                    my: "left-bottom",
                    at: "left-bottom",
                    offsetY: 15
                },
                theme: "rebeccapurple",
                contentSize: {
                    width: 600,
                    height: 350
                },
                headerTitle: attributes.panelcaption,
                content: contenthtml,
            });
            //  });
        }
        return linkFunction;
    }
    return directive;
});
```

And using like following in html

```
<div jspanelcontent panelcaption="list">
  <div ng-controller="ListController">
    {{test}}
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
      <span><a href="{{user.id}}">{{user.id}}</a></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span>{{user.name}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span>{{user.email}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
```

The console log returns as
[image: console log]

Output i am getting (jsPanel)
[image: Output]

As you see the "test" variable is properly bind and the `ng-repeat` element is display as commented, I am not aware why it's returning like that. If anyone can figure out the issue, then i might get it working. 

I know i can access the `users` data as `$scope.users` inside the directive. The problem here is that user able to use the directive commonly, so i have to assume that i don't the variables in the `$scope`.
I stuck in this place, and couldn't find any solutions to try. Any suggestions or solutions will be more helpful. :)

**NOTE: No syntax errors, outside the directive the data is displaying (Tested)**